# Why is this Sinatra API getting an empty response body from this pure JavaScript POST request

Tags: javascript, xml, api, post, sinatra

The route in Sinatra:

```
post '/favorite' do
  response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  p response
end
```

The JS:

note: this isn't all of it, its the relevant bits. It leaves out how the favorited movie is created, but I promise that when I console log it it returns the expected, as noted below

```
window.onload = function(){
  var myApp = new App;
  myApp.addEventListenerToFavoriteButton();
};

var App = function(){
  this.myMovies = null
};

App.prototype.addEventListenerToFavoriteButton = function(){
  var self = this;
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button'){
      self.favorite(event.target.id);
    }
  });
};

App.prototype.favorite = function(movieID){
  var favoritedMovie = this.myMovies.movies[movieID]
  console.log(JSON.stringify(favoritedMovie)) // {title":"Yo soy Betty la fea","year":"1999–2001","imdbID":"tt0233127","html":"<h2>Yo soy Betty, la fea</h2><h3>1999–2001</h3><br><button id='0'>favorite</button>"}
  var url = "http://localhost:4567/favorite";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', encodeURI(url), true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type",'application/json');
  xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200 ) {
          console.log('tentative success!' + xhr.responseText); // tentative success!
      }
      else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
          alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
      }
  };
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(favoritedMovie));
}

var Movie = function(movieObject, index){
   this.title = movieObject['Title'],
   this.year = movieObject['Year'],
   this.imdbID = movieObject['imdbID']
   this.html = "<h2>" + this.title + "</h2><h3>" + this.year + "</h3><br><button id='" + index + "'>favorite</button>"
}
```

Response in Sinatra Console:

```
= Sinatra (v1.4.6) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
#<Sinatra::Response:0x007f803b9061c8 @status=200, @header={"Content-Type"=>nil, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*"}, @chunked=false, @writer=#<Proc:0x007f803b905ea8@/Users/awhit012/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/response.rb:30 (lambda)>, @block=nil, @length=0, @body=[]>
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2015:17:34:17 -0700] "POST /favorite HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0102
```

I've tried adding

```
content_type :json
```

to the route. This makes one difference:

```
@header={"Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*"}
```

which seems better to me, but the body is still empty.

Comment: I your source code online somewhere?

Comment: JS: https://github.com/awhit012/movies
Sinatra: https://github.com/awhit012/movies_back_end

Comment: The source code does not correspond to the code you've posted here, so it's a bit confusing. Your question is also confusing. I think that you are confusing `Sinatra::Request` with `Sinatra::Response`. The `Sinatra::Request` object contains the query sent by your `xhr` object in the Javascript code, the `Sinatra::Response` object is what your route is going to send back to the Javascript code (and will be received by `xhr.onload`).

Comment: oh my god thank you. I was confusing those two. Sorry this was confusing. It was because I was confused. Go figure. I'll post the solution later today.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to  user846250 !
The issue was confusing Sinatra::Request with Sinatra::Response, and Sinatra::Headers

```
post '/favorite' do
  headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
  p request
end
```

That did it.